# Continuous everywhere differentiable nowhere solution to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, fractals

I was reading about calculus the other day, and for some reason I found out about [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), a function that is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere.

---

Now, I do know there are some differential equation whose solution is continuous everywhere, but not necessarily differentiable everywhere (i.e., solution to [Particle in a Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box)).

---

My question is, are there any differential equation whose solution is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere? Or is that impossible?

Comment: @geetha290krm  The Weierstrass function is integrable, so you could have a differential equation with the derivative of that integral

Comment: @Henry You are right. I misread the question.

Comment: Perhaps it depends on your definition of _differential equation_, but to me a first-order ODE is an equation of the form $f(t, y, y')=0$ for some ("reasonably nice") function $f$. If $y'$ doesn't exist anywhere, then either (i) the equation doesn't make sense, or (ii) $f$ does not depend on $y'$, and I wouldn't say we have a _differential equation_. <> Is that what you're asking?